# Trying to understand Single Responsiblity Principle

Tags: object-oriented, solid

I'm having a difficult time understanding the `Single Responsibility Principle`.

What should I look for to evaluate the various sources of information on the matter?
What should I look for in examples explaining the principle?

Comment: Isn't that more of an Object Thinking principle, than an Agile one?

Comment: This question should either be deleted, or be rephrased so it isn't just asking for a link to a tutorial.

Answer (score 7):

SRP is a fairly straight-forward principle.

> the single responsibility principle
>   states that every object should have a
>   single responsibility, and that
>   responsibility should be entirely
>   encapsulated by the class. All its
>   services should be narrowly aligned
>   with that responsibility.

-- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

> A class should have one, and only one,
>   reason to change.

-- http://www.butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod

Often, I find the second quote more applicable.  I try to envision what my class does.  What logic does it contain, or what external (to the class) services might it depend on.

I try to think about what might change, and how might this cause my class to change.  Are there multiple things that could change and affect my class?  That is a code smell (but not always reason enough to split a class).

Also, while I'm thinking along these lines, I look for cases where several classes will need to change if one other thing changes (logic, and external service, etc.).  This too is a code smell.

Often, though, I have small groups of tightly coupled classes that coordinate or interact to perform a single function or service.  If the changes occur across this set of tightly coupled classes, I find that ok.  But if a change in, say, an external service requires changes in multiple classes in different areas of my application, that is a stinkier code smell.

Answer (score 2):

Pluralsight has a course [*Principles of Object Oriented Design*](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=principles-oo-design) that covers SRP as the first topic in about 12 minutes. I believe you get a couple of hours of video for free, after that you need a subscription.